# Frisby.js run tests in loop

Tags: frisby.js

this might be a really basic question:

I want to run a test a 100times:

```
it(testData.TechnicalObject.TC001.Description, function () {
  return frisby.get('https://coma.bmwgroup.net/web/start/').expect('status', 210);
});
```

I was thinking about doing this in a for loop but the statement needs a `return`. How can I achive that the test executes the get 100times?

Answer (score 0):

Create a .bat file and then pass your credentials like `URL=192.168.1.XX:XX, HTTPMODE=https, USERNAME=test PASSWORD=123 ENCRYPTION=OFF, ITERATION=1, COMPANYID=XXXXXXX`

and pass %%n with your username so it not same in next iteration and also make a bat file that manage your iteration and your can easily pass it on cmd.

Thanks